# The module root could not be found. There is nothing to output

Tags: terraform

Running a `terraform output` in my root Terraform directory I get:

```
The module root could not be found. There is nothing to output.
```

I have the following files:

`iam.tf`:

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "a_user" {
  name = "a_user"
}
```

`output.tf`:

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

output "account_id" {
  value = "${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}"
}
```

This https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/index.html says:

```
Root module That is the current working directory when you run terraform apply or get, holding the Terraform configuration files. It is itself a valid module.
```

Any idea why the error message and how to fix?

Answer (score 11):

Terraform refers `root module` from `terraform.tfstate` file.

This file conatains all info about your last known state from `.tf` files along with `output variables`.

Which is generated after first execution `terraform apply` command into current directory.

Simply run `terraform apply`
, then `terraform output` will shows your output variables.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added your module config above, but assuming you have a module file then you have to tell terraform about the source. if the source is a sub directory called example in the same location as iam.tf and output.tf, then you have to add module as bellow, then run terraform apply from the directory where output.tf and iam.tf are:

```
module "consul" {
  source = "./example"

}
```

If your output is a remote location (e.g github) then source has to be as below

```
module "consul" {
  source = "github.com/some-git.git"

}
```

Then you have to run "terraform get" to download your module. Then "terraform apply" to apply the module, then "terraform output" to list the output you specified above

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have not added your module config file. Something along

```
module "test_module" {
  source = "./test_module"
}
```

You have to make sure the module config exists and also the source is valid. To get output, you need a state file which is created after running terraform apply. Looks like you either dont have one or you have no output in your state file.